# html 5 video element

Tags: html

what is the difference between embedding a video in a web page using the embed element versus using a video element(newly introduced in HTML 5)? 
how does it matter if a third party plugin is required to play the video in the former case or if inherent browser support itself is required as in the latter case?

Comment: to further clarify my question i'd like to state the following :-
even if we talk of the video element, all the browsers need to agree on a particular video player that they will have inherent support for and a lot of resources on the internet state that video.js is the player we are talking about. so even here we have a player(video.js). so how does it differ from any other 3rd party plugin that'll otherwise be required to play the video/audio.

Comment: go through this article [HTML5 - Video](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML5_video)

Comment: i have already gone through this article but it mostly deals with the debate on what video format should the browsers support. contrary to this my question is what difference does it make if you use a third party plugin to play the embedded videos or you use an inherent player to play the videos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is one practical difference: a plugin is a separate piece of software that needs to be installed on the system. Hence, the plugin must be *available* for the system the end user has. If your site gets a visitor using Mac PowerPC (it's not *that* old), are you sure that the plugin you've chosen for video will work there? What about Linux or Solaris? What about iPhone?

When web browsers create the VIDEO tag and try to assume the responsibility for playing video, it simplifies some things: it becomes easier to check if a certain video format can be viewed and you need to worry only about browser version (which is easy to detect), not about operating system, what plugins are installed, and what versions of the plugins the user has.

Naturally, with development happening incrementally reality is more complicated than we'd like it to be - so for the time being you should probably serve video in several formats, one of them should probably be flv..

Comment: thank you for the response. i did figure it out to some extent that it had something to do with the different end user platforms. So this is one of the advantages of having the standard VIDEO element. It's be nice if you could cite some more benefits. Thanks anyways for the above reply.